# C# how to keep searching for the items in my list instead of app just closing after one search

Tags: c#

Thank you for helping, I am brand new with programming, I have tried to google but cant find an answer.

What I am looking for is a way for me to continue to search for items in my list without it closing after only one search. Thank you so much!

the code I have tried is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string appName = "Fruitsalad Jens";
        string appVersion = "1.0.0";
        string appAuthor = "Jens Jonassen";

        // Farge
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

        // Versjon
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Versjon {1} by {2}", appName, appVersion, appAuthor);

        // Tilbakestill Fargen
        Console.ResetColor();

        // Velkomst
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, who are you?");

        string navn = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to fruit finder {0}! Which fruit do you need to find?", navn);

        {
            string sSearch;

            List<Frukter> listFrukter = new List<Frukter>();
            listFrukter.Add(new Frukter());
            listFrukter[0].Navn = "Orange";
            listFrukter[0].Pris = 32.5;

            listFrukter.Add(new Frukter());
            listFrukter[1].Navn = "Apple";
            listFrukter[1].Pris = 23;

            listFrukter.Add(new Frukter());
            listFrukter[2].Navn = "Grapes";
            listFrukter[2].Pris = 18.90;

            listFrukter.Add(new Frukter());
            listFrukter[3].Navn = "Mango";
            listFrukter[3].Pris = 48;

            sSearch = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int iCount = 0; iCount < listFrukter.Count; iCount++)

            {

                if (listFrukter[iCount].Navn.Equals(sSearch))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found it!");
                    Console.WriteLine(listFrukter[iCount].getData());

                }

            }


            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You would want to take a look at 'while loops' or 'do - while loops'. They loop (or repeat) a piece of code until a specific condition is met. 'While loops' will check the condition before doing anything. 'Do - while loops' will run at least once before checking the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `while` loop: while user wants to keep searching do it:

```
     ...
     // keep on looping (infinite loop)...
     while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to fruit finder {0}! Which fruit do you need to find? Q for quit", navn);

        sSearch = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

        // ... until user enters "q" for quit
        if (string.Equals(sSearch, "Q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            break;

        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < listFrukter.Count; iCount++)
        {

            if (listFrukter[iCount].Navn.Equals(sSearch))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found it!");
                Console.WriteLine(listFrukter[iCount].getData());
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    ...
```

**Edit:** Same idea (looping) in different implementation (see Pol Vilarrasa's comment below):

```
     // loop once and more if user wants to search again
     do {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to fruit finder {0}! Which fruit do you need to find?", navn);

        sSearch = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < listFrukter.Count; iCount++)
        {
            if (listFrukter[iCount].Navn.Equals(sSearch))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found it!");
                Console.WriteLine(listFrukter[iCount].getData());
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Another search Y/ N?");

        sSearch = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
    }
    while (string.Equals(sSearch, "Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    ...
```

Comment: I don’t think a while(true) loop is a nice answer, because you have an infinite loop that would only end when finishing the program. It would be better to have like an exit command let’s say: type ‘0’ to exit the program, and control the while loop through that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [while loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while). This construct takes a boolean expression, and repeatedly executes the code in its body *while* the expression returns `true`.

For example, the following code will print the numbers 0 to 9 to the console:

```cs
int i = 0;
while(i < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Be careful with loops, because if the condition will never evaluate to `false` the loop will continue forever. In the example, if we would remove `i = i + 1;`, the loop would never terminate, since `i` will always be 0.

In your case, you probably just want to use `while(true)`, since you *want* to repeat your search indefinitely. Everything from reading the user input to printing the response should be part of the `while` body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any sample code around but this was a typical example of programming exercises.

If I understand it correctly you want to keep searching for others fruits after the first search.

You need to add a loop so after finishing the search you return to check the input again, something like this:

```
sSearch = Console.ReadLine();
while (sSearch != "exit")
{
        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < listFrukter.Count; iCount++)
        {
            if (listFrukter[iCount].Navn.Equals(sSearch))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found it!");
                Console.WriteLine(listFrukter[iCount].getData());
            }
        }

    sSearch = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the Console.Readline() inside a while loop. And break from inner for loop once you find an item.

```
Console.WriteLine("Press ESC to stop");

while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape))
{
       sSearch = Console.ReadLine();

       for(int iCount = 0; iCount < listFrukter.Count; iCount++)

           {

               if (listFrukter[iCount].Navn.Equals(sSearch))
                {
                   Console.WriteLine("Found it!");
                   Console.WriteLine(listFrukter[iCount].getData());
                   break;
                }

           }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear correct - how does this allow them to search multiple times? This would prompt the user to search once for each item in the list.